# What happens if I assign a task to a sharepoint group, with inside it an AD group

Tags: groups

I am using SP2010.

I have a vs workflow and I create a task with some body and title. I assign the task to a sharepoint group. For example SPGroupA. Inside this Sharepoint group I have added a AD group. For example ADGroupA. In AD I have 2 user accounts in user group ADGroupA. Do these 2 users receive an email because the task is assigned to them?

Or only the users which are directly inside the SPGroupA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users in your SPGroupA will receive the task notification mail no matter if they are assigned to that group directly or via a sub (or AD) group.